# ESXi Host backup including extra vibs

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, disaster-recovery

I have a licensed ESXI Host with a couple of extra vibs (Chelsio, NVidia, dell) installed. I also have vcenter standard. More that I like to I discover that I have to reinstall the host, e.g. VMware now deprecating SDcards. I'm installing the vibs via ssh on the host. Maybe I should do it through vcenter?

Is there a best practice to create a backup host or of the host config **including** the vibs? Is there a way to restore an esxi host to bare metal including those vibs? I couldnt find anything. In best case I would have a DR backup of the host that I can restore with a few clicks without having to ssh in to install those 3rd party vibs. cheers Chris

Answer (score 3):

1. VIBs can be installed with vSphere Update(or Lifecycle Manager) - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005205
2. Installed vibs are not included in ESXi/vSphere host configuration backup. So, all vibs should be reinstalled after restore. But you can create custom ESXi image with all necessary vibs included - https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.install.doc/GUID-48AC6D6A-B936-4585-8720-A1F344E366F9.html